# Project will not recognize any of maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar

I get the following error when I `maven install` my **Project**:

```
Failed to execute goal on project xxx Could not resolve dependencies for project yyy:xxx:1.0: 
Failed to collect dependencies for [log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.9 (compile), junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (compile), yyy:framework:jar:1.0 (compile), ant:ant:jar:1.6.2 (compile), 
commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.6.1 (compile), commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1 (compile), 
commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.1 (compile), commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.5 (compile), 
commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.0 (compile), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.0 (compile), 
commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3 (compile), commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.2 (compile), 
commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.0.2 (compile), xalan:xalan:jar:2.5.1 (compile), 
xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.4.0 (compile), xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2 (compile), com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:9.0.2.0.0 (compile),
 hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.7.1 (compile), p6spy:p6spy:jar:1.1 (compile), hibernate:hibernate:jar:2.1.6 (compile), 
 javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1 (compile), ehcache:ehcache:jar:0.9 (compile), c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.8.4.5 (compile), 
cglib:cglib:jar:2.0.1 (compile), dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.4 (compile), odmg:odmg:jar:3.0 (compile), 
 javax.xxx:xxx:jar:api:2.1 (compile), com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.3.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile),
 org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8 (compile), xdoclet:xdoclet-ejb-module:jar:1.2.3 (compile), 
 xdoclet:xdoclet:jar:1.2.3 (compile), xdoclet:xdoclet-hibernate-module:jar:1.2.3 (compile), 
 xdoclet:xjavadoc:jar:1.5 (runtime)]:
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.4-dev: Could not transfer artifact commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:pom:1.4-dev: ConnectException: UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1]
```

These **dependencies** are all included in my `pom.xml`.  Any idea of how to solve this?  I have tried adding a settings.xml, but in vain.
`Settings.xml` :

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>C:\Users\abc\.m2\repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers/>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
```

Please help, I am stuck.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Bunti: No, don't think so.

Comment: do you have settings file name with uppercase?

Comment: do you have libraries in your maven repository? check if you have jars for `commons-beanutils` if not try download manually to repository and then install maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your settings.xml to point towards one or more repositories that host the artifacts that you're looking for. They will be downloaded into your local repository. For example:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>central</id>
        <activation>
           <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: I need to change the URL to the folder where there is my repository?

Comment: Maven needs to know where to download the dependencies from. If all of your dependencies are in one place, such as Maven Central or your company's internal Artifactory, then you only need to point towards one repo.

Comment: You need to populate your local repository with the required dependencies. The easiest way would be to point towards a remote repo that contains all the dependencies and let Maven do it for you. Alternatively, you could manually populate your local repository. For example, for p6spy, download the jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/p6spy/p6spy/1.1, run "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=p6spy-1.1.jar -DgroupId=p6spy -DartifactId=p6spy -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can read files of other users on computer. Relocate your maven repository to another path, for example C:/maven_repository and change in your maven settings the local path. This case works for me.

Comment: The settings.xml is in my own user account.

Comment: anyway try change location of your maven repository